# What does "$<" mean when used in a g++ argument?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using a library which has a sample application. The sample makefile contains `$<` in the arguments:

```
all:test.cpp
    g++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -o Example $<
clean:
    rm -f SampleApp11
```

I've looked this up and [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_macros.htm) say that

> $< the name of the related file that caused the action.

Another [website](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html) states that:

> this is a suffix replacement rule for building .o's from .c's
>   it uses automatic variables $<: the name of the prerequisite of
>   the rule(a .c file) and $@: the name of the target of the rule (a .o file) 
>   (see the gnu make manual section about automatic variables)
>   .c.o:
>   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

I am still confused, what does this means?

Comment: In your example its the **first** dependency (file) after the `all:` target - `test.cpp`.

Comment: Ahh, so `<$` tells g++ which file to compile, is that correct?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with g++. It's make which replaces this before calling g++. g++ never sees `$<`. If it did, it would treat it as a file name, and likely issue an error message about no file by that name being found.

Comment: Changing the line to `echo test: $<` would have told you what it does, then you could have looked it up in the documentation for the right tool (_not_ GCC!) to learn what it means. Try to get used to performing research and experimentation in this manner.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Apologies, I did a significant amount of research and was still unclear/confused. It's my first week of writing C/C++ code and compiling it - my previous experience was with interpreted languages.

Comment: I'm sure that even in the world of interpreted languages you are familiar with performing research and experimentation :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually nothing to do with the compiler, its part of the `Makefile` syntax and it is substituted before the compiler is run.

In your example it's the **first** dependency (file) after the `all:` target - `test.cpp`.

The basic function of the `Makefile` is to create a **target** if a **dependency** changes:

```
target: dependency.cpp
    rule to create target (using dependency.cpp)
```

Typically `$<` is the **input** to the compiler and `$@` is the **output**.

It's sort of as if it was this (not a valid `Makefile`):

```
$@: $<
    g++ -o $@ $<
```

The way I remember them is `@` resembles a target (as in target practice) and `<` resembles an arrow. So I imagine an *arrow* pointing to a *target*:

```
@ <-------- (think "Robin Hood")
```

**YMMV**

Answer (score 9):

It is one of [GNU make's automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

> The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from
>   an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the
>   implicit rule (see [Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules)).

A prerequisite is a file listed in the [rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax):

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipe
```

For example, in the following rule the first prerequisite is `test.c` file:

```
my_executable: test.c precompiled.o
    g++ -o my_executable $<
```

It is equivalent to the following:

```
my_executable: test.c precompiled.o
    g++ -o my_executable test.c
```

And the `precompiled.o` is the second prerequisite (a precompiled object file implied).